# EF6 setting default property disables change tracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

Working with EF6 WebApi on .NET 4.7 and hitting an issue when trying to save a model update when we're setting a default value. I'm using the below pattern to save a JSON property in EF6, and it's worked well for a number of classes:

```
public class User 
{
...
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AddressName { get; set; }
    // New fields for mapping 1-N Address
    [NotMapped]
    public List<Address> Addresses
    {
        get { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Address>>(AddressesJson ?? string.Empty); }
        set { AddressesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value); }
    }
    [MaxLength(5000), JsonIgnore]
    public string AddressesJson { get; set; }
...
}

public class Address
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The issue arises when we try to set a default value. We want to migrate the existing Address on the User object if the `Addresses == null`. So we tried the below:

```
public class User 
{
...
    [NotMapped]
    public List<Address> Addresses
    {
        get { return AddressesJson == null ? AddressesDefault : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Address>>(AddressesJson ?? string.Empty); }
        set { AddressesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value); }
    }
    [MaxLength(5000), JsonIgnore]
    public string AddressesJson { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    internal List<Address> AddressesDefault {
        get 
        {
            var defaultAddress = new List<Address>();
            defaultAddress.Add(new Address() { Id = AddressId, Name = AddressName });
            return defaultAddress;
        }
    }

...
}
```

I would have assumed that if the `AddressesJson` backing field was null, I would return a new object that is populated with some default values, which is working. But when I do a HTTP PUT to update the `Addresses` field (and hence the `AddressesJson` backing field), it's not being set and is always returning `AddressesDefault`.

What am I missing? Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: Could you please add some more code from your Controller and your Repository? It's not clear in which order your actions are performed.

Comment: What's interesting is that if I PUT to the controller (sample below) the User object Addresses property is always the default data, never the data sent via HTTP PUT. '
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutUser(int id, User user)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
`

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry my english. I have no reputation to comment, so I will comment here in the Answer section:*

First remark: when you're using `Addresses` getter, you're already checking `AddressesJson == null`, so you don't need call `AddressesJson ?? string.Empty`, because at this point, `AddressesJson` will never be null.
You can remove `?? string.Empty`.

Second: have you been using `Addresses.Add()` at some point?
Note when you add an address with Addresses.Add(someAddress), your `AddressesJson` is not changing.
If true, in this case, I recommend the following approach:

- Create an `AddAddress()` method inside the `User` class. Then you can update `AddressesJson`:

```cs
public void AddAddress(Address newAddress)
{
    // add to list
    Addresses.Add(newAddress);

    // updates json with new address added
    AddressesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Addresses);
}
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: First remark =  thats just copy/paste of me trying a few different ways to set the object if it's null. Won't have impact on end result tho. Second remark = thank, I'm trying to avoid that as will mean a bunch of refactoring on the UI side of things, which is what I'm trying to avoid 